# Правильная реализация MVC на ES6?

Tags: javascript, ооп, mvc, ecmascript-6

Добрый день!
Не могу понять, как правильно реализовать MVC паттерн, вот пример кода:

```
class View {
    exampleMethod() {
        var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
       btnClose.addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log(this.arr);
});
    }
}

class Model {
    constructor() {
        this.arr = ['1'];
    }
}

class Controller {
    constructor(view,model) {
        this.view = view
        this.model = model
    }

}

const myView = new View()
const myModel = new Model()

const myController = new Controller(myView,myModel)
```

Я не понимаю, как правильно связать `view`, что бы при клике отображалось значение в `module` ?
Надеюсь доступно объяснил, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в javascript это реализовать, а на c# это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
class Program
{
    class View
    {
        public Controller Controller { get; set; }
        public void show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Controller.Model.Value);
        }
    }

    class Model
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Model()
        {
            Value = "1";
        }
    }

    class Controller
    {
        public View View { get; set; }
        public Model Model { get; set; }
        public Controller(View view, Model model)
        {
            View = view;
            Model = model;
            View.Controller = this;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Controller myController = new Controller(new View(), new Model());
        myController.View.show();
        myController.Model.Value = "2";
        myController.View.show();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Основная идея такая:

Model - содержит структуру данных.

Controller - Может играться с заполнением данных и вызовом вывода этих данных в интерфейс для пользователя.

View - содержит методы, которые отображают те данные, которые были заполнены в структуре Model контроллером.

---

При этом:

Model - ничего не знает о том, как данные будут отображаться. Возможно, в этих классах также реализация по заполнению и обработке данных (не только в контроллере)

View - ничего не знает о том, откуда получаются и как данные обрабатываются. Знает только о том, куда и как эти данные отобразить.

Controller - Ничего не знает об отображении данных. В принципе, может вообще ничего не знать о том, как данные заполняются и обрабатываются (если логика перенесена в Model). Знает только что данные хранятся в Model и выводятся через View.

Comment: если кого-то смущает связь View и Controller через View.Controller = this; то это я сделал для примера. Данная связь может быть реализована разными способами. Например, глобальной переменной Controller или передачей непосредственно данных из Model в методы View как параметры.

Answer (score 0):

> Я не понимаю как правильно связать view, что бы при клике отображалось значение в module ?

В данном случае, логично связать через контроллер. Хотя можно и напрямую (например, передавая конструктору представления ссылку на модель). Второй вариант удобен когда представление само периодически выводит данные, без участия пользователя.

---

Проблема вашего кода в том что `view` пытается получить `arr` как свое свойство, хотя это свойство `model`.

---

Если развивать ваш пример, я бы сделал так (связь через контроллер, так как данные выводятся по нажатию на кнопку):

```js
class View {
  log(data) {
    console.clear(); 
    console.log(data.join(', ') || 'Нет данных');
  }
  reportOk(el) {
    el.style.animation = 'green-bg 0.5s ease-in reverse'; 
    setTimeout(() => {
      el.style.animation = null; 
    }, 500); 
  }
}; 

class Model {
  constructor()   { this.arr = []; }
  get data()      { return this.arr; }
  set data(value) { this.arr = value.slice(); }
  sort() { this.arr.sort((a, b) => a - b); }
}; 

class Controller {
  constructor(view, model) {
    this.view  = view  || new View(); 
    this.model = model || new Model(); 
  }
  eventHandler(e) {
    switch (e.target.getAttribute('mvc-do')) {
      case 'log': 
        this.view.log(this.model.data); 
        break; 
      case 'add': 
        let newData = [], 
            len = e.target.getAttribute('mvc-len') || 5; 
        for (let i = 0; i < +len; i++)
          newData[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); 
        this.model.data = newData; 
        newData.splice(0, newData.length); 
        break; 
      case 'sort': 
        this.model.data.sort(); 
        break; 
      default: 
        return; 
    }
    this.view.reportOk(e.target); 
  }
  connectElements(selector, event) {
    let els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (let el of els)
      el.addEventListener(event, e => this.eventHandler(e)); 
  }
}; 


const myView  = new View(), 
      myModel = new Model(), 
      myController = new Controller(myView, myModel); 
//const myController = new Controller(); 
myController.connectElements('button', 'click');
```

```css
button {
  margin: 10px 5px; padding: 4px 12px; 
  font: 18px sans-serif; 
}

@keyframes green-bg { to { background-color: #7e7; } }
```

```html
<button mvc-do="add" mvc-len="12">Новые данные</button>
<button mvc-do="sort">Отсортировать</button>
<button mvc-do="log">Вывести в консоль</button>
```

*Данный пример кода **не претендует** на соответствие каким-либо канонам и/или шаблонам.*